# Shmos 2:15 – Moshe fled from Paroh and dwelt in Midian. Why Midian?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, geography, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos

[Shmos 2:15](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=14126&st=%u05de%u05d3%u05d9%u05df) – Moshe fled from Paroh and dwelt in Midian.

Why did he choose Midian?

The only slightly helpful references I saw said

a)  *(attributed to a Medrash but I do not see it)* that he was miraculously transported to Midian (and so I guess stayed where he was deposited) or

b)  *(attributed to Rashbam but I do not see it)* that he was bound for somewhere else and not intending to stay in Midian but having met Tziporah decided to stay.

Alshich says that he stayed in Cush for some time but since nothing of importance happened there, the Torah does not mention it but it is mentioned in Divrei Hayomim and again I have not been able to find the reference.

Comment: The "Divrei Hayomim" refers to the Divrei Hayomim of Moshe Rabbeinu brought in the [Yalkut Shimoni on parshas Shemos](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14573&st=&pgnum=102) and which I partially translated for another post [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35807/did-moses-marry-twice/35834#35834).

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - Do you know of a better place he should have gone instead?

Comment: @Shmuel Good question. Instead of going east, he could have gone west inthe direction of modern Libya.

Comment: If he'd gone West, he would have never ended up at Chorev, and would have never seen God in the Burning Bush. (Of course, God still could have spoken to him, but it wouldn't've been at Har Sinai, with all that that connotes.)

Comment: Also, due to a lack of information, we must assume that he chose the best place to run to given the circumstances.

Comment: Not totally related but Midian appeared to be split into two parts. The other part was the one massacred after the incident of Zimri and Cosbi. Presumably the one to which Moshe fled survived and provided the Midianites who subsequently fought in Gidon's time.

Answer (score 3):

[Rabeinu Bachya](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30835&st=&pgnum=13&hilite=) says that Moshe feared the long arm of Pharoh and felt that if he married one of the daughters of one of the Kohanim (Yisro was Kohain Midyan) then he would be safe. He went to Midyan since Yisro had 7 daughters so he figured there is a better chance one of them would be willing to marry him. Through that he would come under Yisro's protection and he would be safe.

Comment: I don't think he is saying that is why Moshe went there to begin with, as per OP's request. He is giving reasons why Moshe involved himself with Yisro once he was there.

Comment: I reread Rabeinu Bachya and I stand by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Someone running away (as Moshe was from Paroh) hardly could have a particular place in mind where to hide. The further away from people (who could denounce him), the better. According to Rashbam, he was passing through Midian as travelers used to do (to rest). Per [Ibn Ezra](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=2&perek=2&mefaresh=ezra), Moshe 'chose' then to become a shepherd there because if he decided to live (continually) in a settlement area people would recognize him.

Comment: [ב, טו]
וישמע -
ארץ מדין סרים היו אל משמעת פרעה, על כן הוצרך להיות רועה צאן, שלא יעמוד בישוב אולי יכירוהו. If this what you are referring to I disagree. Heis not saying why he went to Midyan like the OP requested, he is saying why he chose to be a shepherd once he was there. If anything this makes the question stronger. Why head to Midyan if the officials there were close to Paroh.

Comment: I edited my reasoning. It was based also on Rashbam that the OP had already mentioned. I hope it's clear now.