# Did Moses divorce Tziporah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hebrew, parashas-yisro, ki-teitzei

Exodus 18:2:

> וַיִּקַּ֗ח יִתְרוֹ֙ חֹתֵ֣ן מֹשֶׁ֔ה אֶת־צִפֹּרָ֖ה אֵ֣שֶׁת מֹשֶׁ֑ה
>   אַחַ֖ר **שִׁלּוּחֶֽיהָ׃**
>
> And Jethro, Moses’father-in-law, took Zipporah, Moses’wife, after he
>   had sent her away

In the Bible, the term שלח when mentioned in this context regarding women is also a term that implies divorce, as we see in Deuteronomy 24:1:

> כִּֽי־יִקַּ֥ח אִ֛ישׁ אִשָּׁ֖ה וּבְעָלָ֑הּ וְהָיָ֞ה אִם־לֹ֧א
>   תִמְצָא־חֵ֣ן בְּעֵינָ֗יו כִּי־מָ֤צָא בָהּ֙ עֶרְוַ֣ת דָּבָ֔ר וְכָ֨תַב
>   לָ֜הּ סֵ֤פֶר כְּרִיתֻת֙ וְנָתַ֣ן בְּיָדָ֔הּ וְשִׁלְּחָ֖הּ מִבֵּיתֽוֹ׃

(Sefaria translation)

> When a man taketh a wife, and marrieth her, then it cometh to pass, if
>   she find no favour in his eyes, because he hath found some unseemly
>   thing in her, that he writeth her a bill of divorcement, and giveth it
>   in her hand, and sendeth her out of his house,

The verse in Shemot seems to have a similar context, in that Moses "sent Tziporah away" which seems to imply divorce.

Were they divorced? If yes, then why is she called "Moses' wife" if she is not actually his wife any more?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8211/759

Comment: I dont really think that's a dupe. That is talking about in the desert, this is talking about before yitro came

Answer (score 3):

Your connection is exactly what the Malbim discusses, I copied the relevant part here (partial emphasis by me):

> **וישמע יתרו.** בא להציע מה הניע את לב יתרו לצאת ממדין אל המדבר ולהביא את בניו אתו, שהלא מנמוסי הכבוד היה ראוי שמשה ישחר פני חותנו והוא ישלח אחר אשתו, כמ"ש דרכו של איש לחזר אחר אשה לא בהפך שנקבה תסובב גבר, זאת שנית הלא משה שלח את אשתו **בגט פטורין**, כמ"ש אחר שלוחיה ות"א בתר דפטרה, שזה תרגום של שלוח בגט או שלוח עבד בגט שחרור, וכלל בלשון שלשון שלוח בבנין הכבד אצל אשה מציין גירושין בכ"מ, וכ"כ בילקוט שגרשה בגט פטורין, ואיך הכניע א"ע להביא לו אשתו ששלחה ונפרדה מאתו...‏
>   
> ...
>   
> **ויקח יתרו... אחר שלוחיה**. הגם ששלח אותה ונפרד ממנה לא חש לזה, כי לא עשה זה בעבור שמאס בה, כי היא עדיין **אשת משה** גם **אחר שלוחיה**, כי לא נפרד ממנה רק לפי שעה עד יפקוד ה' עמו כנ"ל.‏

In short, the Malbim does indeed say that Moses divorced Tzipporah, and that "שלח" is indeed mostly used for divorce (he brings proof from Onkelos, and the Yalkut, and his own opinion).
So he explains that she is still called "אשת משה" because he only divorced and left her temporarily, not because he didn't want her as his wife.

(Also Ba'al HaTurim says that she is still called his wife, just like no one marries a king's divorced wife.)